# Azure App Service drops connection with http/2 enabled, no errors

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET website that's hosted on Azure App Service. There's a particular page that I cannot visit; Azure App Service drops the connection within a second. The logs show that my website returned with a 200 response. With cURL the output is as follows:

```
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* LibreSSL SSL_read: Connection reset by peer, errno 54
* Failed receiving HTTP2 data: 56(Failure when receiving data from the peer)
* Connection #0 to host my-website.azurewebsites.net left intact
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

The problem is related to http/2 as I can request the page using `--http1.1` just fine. I've so far disabled http/2 on the website and I can now open the page in my browser as well.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation I've found that the particular page has a large response header, to the tune of 24k characters. After removing this header, the page loads fine using http/2 as well.